# Cree LED problem

Tags: led, heat, crystal, failure, replacement

We have a production circuit of 24 series/parallel LED arrays. Blocks of LEDs fail on power-up.

Has anyone seen this before? The sequence of events is:

1. An LED tests as bad in circuit.
2. LED is removed and tested. LED works fine.
3. LED is soldered back onto the PCB. Circuit now works fine.

What's happening? Could the heat be doing something to the LED crystal/wire bond?

This is happening across multiple boards and with different LED positions.

Comment: Driven by constant current?

Comment: Define "tests bad"?

Comment: Diode checking in circuit fails to light LED.

Comment: looks like a solder problem. What happens if you just re-solder the LED on the board?

Comment: Is it that the boards used to work and now don't? If so, has anything changed in the soldering process? Could the PCBs be contaminated so that the solder isn't making proper contact?

Comment: The PCB's are wave soldered. There is about a 33% failure rate across the PCB batch with 1 or 2 LED's per board "failing". Reflowing the LED solder joints in circuit doesn't work, you actually have to remove the LED and test it out of circuit. There is no apparent contamination on the boards but I realise this is still a possibility. The solder joints look good though. It's a through hole LED.

Comment: Are you testing on the LED pins or the board tracks? Are the pins coated with anything or pre-tinned?

Comment: On the LED pins, component side.

Comment: Not sure how you post a picture but the LED's are straight out of the tube and look pre tinned.

Comment: Does the in-circuit test suggest an open circuit or short circuit? Or even a diode reversal?

Comment: Are you following the required moisture control for your LEDs? Depending on the device packaging (and your handling) you may need to bake them out before using. SMT LEDs, especially, absorb moisture from the air, under soldering/reflow this then turns into steam internally which causes damage (bond wire damage gives erratic operation!). We had issues with MSL 5a devices which meant we had to bake-out each and every LED, even though they technically should have still been within their working time.

Comment: The ICT was a diode test to light the LED, it wasn't me doing it so I'm not sure what the test showed. Interesting about the moisture control. They could well have been out of the packet for a while (months) but they are through hole so I'd have thought they would be a bit less susceptible. Still, this does sound like it could be the answer.

Comment: @Cursorkeys, please can you delete your comment and post it as an answer instead.